# Meteor.js - add packaging for 3rd party library

Tags: node.js, meteor, phaser-framework

i followed the official meteor instructions for adding package support to 3rd party libraries (source: https://github.com/MeteorCommunity/discussions/issues/14).

When i test the meteor integration with `meteor add` i keep getting an error:

> add: You're not in a Meteor project directory.

I can't figure out whats missing??

EDIT: To be more clear: I ve forked phaser.io to my local devmachine and added a meteor directory to the root of the phaser library. The meteor directory contains export.js, package.js and test.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialise a meteor project directory with:

```
meteor create myappname

cd myappname

meteor add mymeteoruser:mypackagename
```

This is assuming you've published your package as per the linked instructions in your question.

You can only add a package if you have already created a meteor app for it to go into (on a really basic level this creates a .meteor folder containing all the necessary bits and pieces to keep track of which packages you have installed)

Comment: got it thanks. but still figuring out how to add a 3rd party library to my project.